# DRF API return a list with filtered lists

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

The data that is returned is one list with all fields. I want the data to be separated in different lists inside the main list. For example a list of data that is filtered on the date before today and a list after the date of today. I could write two endpoints and have the data filtered in the queryset, but that would take two separate API calls.

The viewset:

```
class StudyPageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    Study create, read, update, delete over API.
    """
    model = Study
    serializer_class = StudyPageSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsAuthorPermission,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Study.on_site.all()
```

The Serializer:

```
class StudyPageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Study
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'date', 'location')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

Outcome should be like:

```
[ 
   { 
      "list_before_today":[ 
         { 
            "id":"5001",
            "title":"None"
         },
         { 
            "id":"5002",
            "title":"Glazed"
         },

      ]
   },
   { 
      "list_after_today":[ 
         { 
            "id":"5003",
            "title":"None"
         },
         { 
            "id":"5004",
            "title":"Glazed"
         },

      ]
   },

]
```

Current output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 588,
        "title": "title",
        .. : ..
    },
    {
        "id": 590,
        "title": "title2",
        .. : ..
    },
]
```

ps. the dots represent the other fields.

Comment: Could you show the current response format?

Comment: @ToanQuocHo yeah sure, I'll add it to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, when you call GET request into `ModelViewSet` view, it will call `list` method. Inside list method, Rest framework does use the `Model` to create a queryset to query data and then pass it into `Serializer` to serialize the data and then return it, that's why you got this:

```py
[
    {
        "id": 588,
        "title": "title",
        .. : ..
    },
    {
        "id": 590,
        "title": "title2",
        .. : ..
    },
]
```

So to get the response as your expected, you have to override that `list` method to get the response with the format as your expected, like so:

```py
from datetime import date

from rest_framework import status

class StudyPageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    Study create, read, update, delete over API.
    """
    model = Study
    serializer_class = StudyPageSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsAuthorPermission,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Study.on_site.all()

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        today = date.today()

        output = [{
            "list_before_today": self.get_serializer(queryset.filter(date__lt=today), many=True).data
        }, {
            "list_after_today": self.get_serializer(queryset.filter(date__gt=today), many=True).data
        }]


        return Response(output, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

This is just the idea so you have to align with your code to make it work. I'm also not recommend you to do that because `ModelViewSet` is well-defined by Django Rest Framework, if you want to get that response, you also can create another APIView to handle that.

Hope that helps!

Comment: In the end I used a ReadOnlyViewset to fit my needs. Thank you for this helpful answer